# Ex-post grouping blocks, when analyzing blocked randomization experiment, to avoid $N_b=1$ blocks

Tags: experiment-design, stratification, blocking, design-based-inference

In an experiment I conducted, randomization was stratified geographically and then blocked by the baseline outcome variable, $x$. That is, within each strata, $s$, I grouped observations into blocks, $b$, to minimize variance within blocks of a continuous variable, x. Then, within each block, half of the observations were assigned to treatment, $Z \in \{0,1\}$.

Let $N_b$ be the number of observations in block $b$. [Imbens and Athey (2017)](https://www-sciencedirect-com.proxy.uchicago.edu/science/article/pii/S2214658X16300174), in their handbook chapter on the econometrics of field experiments, recommend that $N_b$ be as small as possible as long as $N_b \geq 4$. This is what I had in mind, however, instead, I did not realize the R package I used for blocking imposed $N_b$ as large as possible as long as $N_b \leq 4$. This created a problem in any strata in which the number of observations is not a multiple of 4.

For example, assume there were 9 observations in a strata:

```
id x   b Z
a  1.0 1 0
b  0.9 1 1
c  0.9 1 0
d  1.1 1 1
e  1.3 2 1
f  2.0 1 1
g  1.9 1 0
h  1.9 1 1
i  2.1 1 0
```

The algorithm grouped:

- $(a,b,c,d)$ into block $b=1$. $N_1=4$
- $e$ into $b=2$. . $N_2=1$
- $(f,g,h,i)$ into into $b=3$. $N_3=4$

However, to avoid $N_2=1$, and still, preserve it would have been ideal to subdivide only into 2 blocks. In this case, $e$ would be assigned to block 1 (because $x_e=1.3$ is closer to the values of x in block 1).

**I was wondering if it would be possible to ex-post regroup these adjacent blocks (in terms of $x$)?**

.

**Does this sound reasonable or sinful?**

.

More generally, the question is about the statistical validity of regrouping Strata (blocks) following a rule that is independent of the experiment's outcome and preserves the spirit of the Strata (blocks).

I was thinking that when conducting the randomization inference, I would still be drawing treatment ($Z$) from the original blocks. But pooling neighboring blocks when estimating mean differences and their estimated variances.

[Note1: Why avoid small blocks? With a block size of 1, I can not compute within block mean differences. And with less than 2 units in each treatment arm per group, I can not compute the within-group variance. And these are necessary building blocks randomization inference.]

[Note2: the package used at the time was `blockTools`. This is not the fault of the package, as its intended use was to do paired stratification (blocks with one observation per treatment status). We adapted for blocking by declaring a paired stratification with 4 treatment arms, which prompted the package to group observations into blocks 4 and leaving the remainder observations into smaller groups.]